# Action/Select a Location in OSM Map and Show Marker

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I am new to OSM API. (Open Street Map)

I'm currently searching for a solution to select (or highlight) a vector in a OpenLayers.
i.e am trying to set a location for user. That user can give his location by clicking on map (Particular location) and then need to do some manipulation with those longitude and latitude.

`JS` Code i have tried

```
 function showVehicleMap(){      

        ltArray = document.getElementById('deviceMonitorRightPaneForm:lat').value.split(",");
        lgArray = document.getElementById('deviceMonitorRightPaneForm:lon').value.split(",");                
        directionArray = document.getElementById('deviceMonitorRightPaneForm:direction').value.split(",");                

        map = createMap("deviceMap");    

        for(var i=0;i<ltArray.length;i++)
        {                                   
            var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( lgArray[i] ,ltArray[i] ).transform(               
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                );                
            pointsArray.push(lonLat);
        }
        //prepare mid point
        var latAvg = document.getElementById('deviceMonitorRightPaneForm:latAvg').value;
        var lonAvg = document.getElementById('deviceMonitorRightPaneForm:lonAvg').value;
        var midpoint       = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lonAvg,latAvg).transform( fromProjection, toProjection);

        //create Marker
        var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );
        map.addLayer(markers);
        //prepare list of markers
        markers = addMarkersByDirection(markers, pointsArray, directionArray);        

        map.zoomToExtent(markers.getDataExtent());
        map.setCenter (midpoint, 9);    

    //
    /* ]]> */   
    }
```

How do i achieve it?

Comment: There are several examples how to interactively set a marker at a user-defined position. See [OSM's new note feature](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Notes), [OpenStreetBugs](http://openstreetbugs.schokokeks.org/) or OSM's own "set home location" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register a mouse click event to get the position via the mouse:

```
map.events.register('click', map, function handleMapClick(e) {
          var clickedLonLat = map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy).transform(map.projection, map.displayProjection);
       ...
       // place a OpenLayers.Layer.Marker at clickedLonLat for visual feedback
       // for convenience: map.panTo(clicketLonLat);
       ...
});
```

Comment: Can u please give detail information in answer. @Christophe Roussy

Comment: Now that you have the keywords you can get detailed information via the API documentation: http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html

Comment: I have tried what you suggested. But am getting wrong 'Lon' 'Lat'. ' map.events.register('click', map, function handleMapClick(e) { lonLat = self.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx(e.xy). transform(map.fromProjection, map.toProjection); ' prompt("",lonLat); }); '

Comment: It may depend on your projection, also have a look at http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html